# Unable to recognise Shibuya account address to deploy an EVM contract on Shibuya network using Truffle

Tags: evm, astar, shibuya

I want to make an XVM call from an ink! contract that is deployed to the Shibuya Wasm environment  to a Solidity EVM contract that is deployed to the Shibuya EVM environment.

To deploy the Solidity EVM contract I want to use Truffle, so I followed the official Astar instructions here https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/builder-guides/astar_features/truffle/ where it says to use  `from: "0x(your Shibuya account address)"` in my Truffle configuration file truffle-config.js, but none of the Shibuya account addresses that I have generated work when I try to migrate the EVM smart contract by running `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all --network shibuya`. The Truffle documentation [here](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/) says that the `from` field is for *"From address used during migrations. Defaults to the first available account provided by your Ethereum client."*

The steps I took to try to resolve it so far include the following. All the code that I've mentioned is published here https://github.com/ltfschoen/XCMTemplate/pull/25 and I was using endpoint `wss://shibuya.public.blastapi.io`:

1. Created a Shibuya address using [Subkey](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/subkey/) using Docker by running `docker run -it --pull=always docker.io/parity/subkey:latest generate --network astar`, which output the following, except I haven't shown the mnemonic phrase and private key below, then I used a faucet to give that address a 10 SBY account balance, which I verified here https://shibuya.subscan.io/account/XXyzohKoEwDWXvpo7CS8unT7rjU6KoiaRm8iE1eWSXMpf3i:

```
  Account ID:        0x46b03bc771e0799dcbc20302e3054b7f34d17e442189bd4acabc822f318afc6d
  Public key (SS58): XXyzohKoEwDWXvpo7CS8unT7rjU6KoiaRm8iE1eWSXMpf3i
```

2. Updated Truffle configuration file truffle-config.js to use that `Account ID`,

```
from: "0x46b03bc771e0799dcbc20302e3054b7f34d17e442189bd4acabc822f318afc6d"
```

3. Ran `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all --network shibuya` to migrate the Solidity EVM contract to Shibuya network using Truffle, but it gave the following error:

```
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.21+commit.d9974bed.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'shibuya'
> Network id:      81
> Block gas limit: 15000000 (0xe4e1c0)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- Provided address 0x46b03bc771e0799dcbc20302e3054b7f34d17e442189bd4acabc822f318afc6d is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted..


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- Provided address 0x46b03bc771e0799dcbc20302e3054b7f34d17e442189bd4acabc822f318afc6d is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted..

    at /Users/luke/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:330:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
Truffle v5.11.0 (core: 5.11.0)
Node v16.18.1
```

4. Went to https://shibuya.subscan.io/tools/format_transform?input=XXyzohKoEwDWXvpo7CS8unT7rjU6KoiaRm8iE1eWSXMpf3i&type=All to see what other addresses the `Public key (SS58)` value of `XXyzohKoEwDWXvpo7CS8unT7rjU6KoiaRm8iE1eWSXMpf3i` that was generated by Subkey would transform into, and it displayed:

```
Public Key
0x46b03bc771e0799dcbc20302e3054b7f34d17e442189bd4acabc822f318afc6d

H160
0x46b03Bc771e0799dcBc20302e3054b7f34d17E44
```

5. I used the `H160` address that was shown for the value of the `from` field instead:

```
from: "0x46b03Bc771e0799dcBc20302e3054b7f34d17E44"
```

But when I ran `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all --network shibuya` it gave error:

```
"Migrations" -- Unknown address - unable to sign transaction for this address: "0x46b03bc771e0799dcbc20302e3054b7f34d17e44".
```

6. Then I tried doing the following in truffle-config.js, but it appears to output a seemlingly **unrelated** address `0xe234aaD61a482eBB5f737ffFd4b868d829eAc455` for the privateKeyShibuya that I provided that was generated by Subkey, and it said it had no funds (since I only used the faucet to get SBY tokens for the account that was actually generated by Subkey).

```js
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
let providerInstance = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(
   process.env.SHIBUYA_ENDPOINT, {}, { delay: 500, autoReconnect: true, maxAttempts: 100 });
let web3 = new Web3(providerInstance);
const accounts = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKeyShibuya);
console.log('accounts:', accounts);
```

outputs

```
accounts: {
  address: '0xe234aaD61a482eBB5f737ffFd4b868d829eAc455',
  privateKey: '...',
  ....
```

7. Then I tried the suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68823402/provided-address-is-invalid-the-capitalization-checksum-test-failed by adding the following to truffle-config.js. I made the assumption that I needed to use the `H160` address `0x46b03Bc771e0799dcBc20302e3054b7f34d17E44`:

```js
...
const accountAddress = "0x46b03Bc771e0799dcBc20302e3054b7f34d17E44";

async function checksumShibuyaAccountAddress(_shibuyaAccountAddress) {
   let providerInstance = await new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(
      process.env.SHIBUYA_ENDPOINT, {}, { delay: 500, autoReconnect: true, maxAttempts: 100 });
   let web3 = await new Web3(providerInstance);
   console.log('web3.currentProvider: ', web3.currentProvider);
   let checksumShibuyaAccountAddress = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(_shibuyaAccountAddress);
   return checksumShibuyaAccountAddress;
}

...

module.exports = {
...
   networks: {
      shibuya: {
         provider: () => {
         from: async () => {
            let from = await checksumShibuyaAccountAddress(accountAddress);
            console.log('checksumShibuyaAccountAddress from: ', from)
            return from;
         },
```

However, that outputs the same error as I got earlier:

```
... is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or it's an indirect IBAN address which can't be converted..
```